# WP_Query is not returning any posts for my custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to create a custom post type (tlc_duck) for the first time and am having trouble figuring out why WP_Query is failing to find any of the posts of my custom type.

I am including the entirety of my test plugin below as it is already stripped down to its essentials for trying to learn how to use custom post types.  I am well aware that this is not safe code as it does no sanitation of inputs and does not use nonces.  Please don't comment on those aspects of the code.

When I click on the "Add a duck" button in the rendered shortcode, I can see in the PHP error log that the code to create a new duck post is run.  If I look in the MySQL database in the wp_posts table, I can see the new tlc_duck entry.  If I look at the "Duck Posts" list in the admin pages, I can see the new duck entry.  So that part is working fine.

But, when I try querying to see the list of all created ducks (See [Lines 77-90](https://github.com/mikemayer67/tlc-survey-posts/blob/master/tlc-survey-posts.php#L77-L90)), the have->posts() is returning false (I'm seeing "no ducks" in the PHP error log).

My guess would be I did something wrong when registering the custom type (See [Lines 31-40](https://github.com/mikemayer67/tlc-survey-posts/blob/master/tlc-survey-posts.php#L31-L40)), but I found the documentation on what each of the features mean to be a little obtuse... as in it is probably pretty helpful if you already know what it means.

What am I missing (or messing up)?

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: TLC Survey Posts
 * Plugin URI: https://github.com/mikemayer67/tlc-survey-posts
 * Description: Plugin to understand how custom post types work
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author: Michael A. Mayer
 * Requires PHP: 5.3.0
 * License: GPLv3
 * License URL: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */

if( ! defined('WPINC') ) { die; }

function tlc_register_post_type()
{
  $labels = array(
   'name' => 'Duck Posts',
   'singular_name' => 'Duck',
   'add_new' => 'New Duck',
   'add_new_item' => 'Add New Duck',
   'edit_item' => 'Edit Duck',
   'new_item' => 'New Ducky',
   'view_item' => 'View Duckies',
   'search_items' => 'Search Ducks',
   'not_found' =>  'No Ducks Found',
   'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Ducks found in Trash',
  );

  $args = array(
   'labels' => $labels,
   'has_archive' => false,
   'public' => false,
   'show_ui' => true,
   'show_in_rest' => false,
  );


  register_post_type('tlc_duck',$args);
}

function tlc_handle_shortcode()
{
  ob_start();

  $form_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

?>
<form method=post action='<?=$form_uri?>'>
  <input type=hidden name=action value=add_duck>
  <input type=submit value="Add a duck">
</form>

<?php
  $html = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $html;
}

function tlc_add_duck()
{
  error_log("Add a duck");
  $duck_args = array(
    'post_content' => 'test duck',
    'post_title' => 'ducky duck',
    'post_type' => 'tlc_duck',
  );
  error_log(print_r($duck_args,true));
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($duck_args,true);
  error_log("added duck: $post_id");

  $qargs = array(
    'post_type' => 'tlc_duck',
  );

  $duck_posts = new WP_Query($qargs);
  if($duck_posts->have_posts())
  {
    while($duck_posts->have_posts())
    {
      $duck = $duck_posts->the_post();
      error_log(print_r($duck,true));
    }
  }
  else
  {
    error_log("No ducks");
  }
}

add_action('init','tlc_register_post_type');
add_shortcode('duck-posts','tlc_handle_shortcode');

$action = $_POST['action'] ?? "";
if( $action == 'add_duck')
{
  error_log("Need to add a duck");
  add_action('init','tlc_add_duck');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected... it was a stupid mistake.

I was not setting post_status to 'publish'.  The query was not finding any ducks because they were all in draft state.

Doh!